# How to avoid changing state in F#?

Tags: f#

I have a `C# WebAPI` application that uses an `F#` library.

The `F#` library has a value:

```
 let mutable CurrentCustomer:Customer option = None
```

I also have:

```
 let Customers:Map<string,Customer> option = None
```

Both `Customers` and `Customer` are "global variables". On start-up the `C#` application loads a collection of customers into this global variable `Customers`. Then I have a `customersController` that has a `Post`, which calls an F# function `setCurrentCustomer` that sets the global variable `CurrentCustomer` from the collection stored in `Customers`:

```
 // Post in customersController:

 public HttpResponseMessage Post(string identifier)
 {
     var _customer = FSharpLibrary.setCurrentCustomer(identifier);
     // code
 }

 // setCurrentCustomer function:

 let mutable CurrentCustomer:Customer option = None
 let setCurrentCustomer() =
     CurrentCustomer <- customer |> Some
     CurrentCustomer
```

Is there any way to avoid changing state by changing `CurrentCustomer`?

I know I could create a function that takes a `CurrentCustomer` object and returns a new `CurrentCustomer` object, but how will the `customersController` know what is the current customer set to?

Is there any way of avoiding having this global **mutable** variable `Customer`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way to avoid changing state by changing CurrentCustomer?

Yes, there are many ways to do that, but most will involve changing the design of your `FSharpLibrary` so that it doesn't rely on mutable state.

As a completely general answer, you could apply the **State Monad**, but something less involved is often sufficient. Exactly what that would be, however, is impossible to answer without knowing *what* you are attempting to accomplish.

> how will the `customersController` know what is the current customer set to?

It already knows, because it's setting the current customer to the `identifier` argument from the `Post` method. That value is in scope throughout the entire method.

The question is why your `FSharpLibrary` has mutable state? Can't you instead implement it with pure functions?